# Error: could not find or load main class BasicTestCase

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, selenium, javac

Okay, I know this has been answered more than once, but so far none of the solutions appear to be working for me.  So at this point I have no idea what is going on.

Let me show you my main class file:

```
package automationFramework;

public class BasicTestCase {

    public static void showResults( String testSuiteName, boolean[] results ) {
        /* Show results of the test pass */
        int passed = 0;

        for( boolean test : results ) {
            passed += test == true ? 1 : 0;
        }

        System.out.println( "\n" + testSuiteName + " results: " + passed + " out of " + results.length + " passed...\n" );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Base test suite */
        LoginTestSuite udxLoginTestSuite = new LoginTestSuite();
        MiscTestSuite udxMiscTestSuite = new MiscTestSuite();

        BaseAutomationSuite[] udxAutomationSuite = new BaseAutomationSuite[] {
            /* Miscellaneous UDX test cases */
            new BaseAutomationSuite() { public void execute() { showResults( "MiscTestSuite",   udxMiscTestSuite.run() ); } },
            /* Login UDX test cases */
            new BaseAutomationSuite() { public void execute() { showResults( "LoginTestSuite",  udxLoginTestSuite.run() ); } }
        };

        /* Execute test suite */
        for( BaseAutomationSuite suite : udxAutomationSuite ) {
            suite.execute();
        }
    }
}
```

That's just the main class, there are a few others.

This here is my batch file:

```
javac^
 -cp "C:\eclipse\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-java-2.53.0.jar;C:\eclipse\selenium-2.53.0\libs\*"^
 src\automationFramework\*.java^
 -d classes/
jar cvfe udxautomator.jar BasicTestCase classes\automationFramework\*.class
java -cp . BasicTestCase
```

My first batch file didn't have the last line which seems to fix the problem for most people, but I still get the same error when using that line.  This is really confusing, and it is my first foray into building a .jar file to run Java code though the command line.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to preserve the package structure for this to work; the fully qualified class name is `automationFramework.BasicTestCase`.

Comment: Tried it, same error.  I added "automationFramework." in front of BasicTestCase on both lines (and each individually) and no success.  Sorry for the slow response, I had to wait until I got back into the office to work on this again.